# Multiclass classification growing number of classes

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am building an intent recognition system using multiclass classfication with SVM.

Currently I only have a few numbers of classes limited by the training data. However, in the future, I may get data with new classes. I can, of course, put all the data together and re-train the model, which is timing consuming and in-efficient.

My current idea is to do the one-against-one classification at the beginning, and when a new class comes in, I can just train it against all the existing classes, and get n new classifiers. I am wondering if there are some other better methods to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I think not. The strategy you propose seems the most efficient because in any case you cannot avoid testing the new instance against every class

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient approach would be to focus on one-class classifiers, then you just need to add one new model to the ensemble. Just to compare:

Let us assume that we have K classes and you get 1 new plus P new points from it, your whole dataset consists of N points (for simpliciy - equaly distributed among classes) and your training algorithm complexity is `f(N)` and if your classifier supports incremental learning then its complexity if `g(P, N)`

- OVO (one vs one) - in order to get the exact results you need to train K new classifiers, each with about N/K datapoints thus leading to `O(K f(P+N/K))`, there is no place to use incremental training
- OVA (one vs all) - in order to get the exact results you retrain all classifiers, if done in batch fassion you need `O(K f(N+P))`, worse than the above. However if you can train in incremental fashion you just need `O(K g(P, N))` which might be better (depending on the classifier).
- One-class ensemble - it might seem a bit weird, but for example Naive Bayes can be seen as such approach, you have generative model which models each class conditional distribution, thus your model for each class is actually independent on the remaining ones. Thus the complexity is `O(f(P))`

This list is obviously not exhaustive but should give you general idea in what to analyze.